# Assembly from a simple simd code: why xmm registers are not used

Tags: c++, simd, disassembly

I am new to simd.  Here is a small example of c++ code:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef __m128d simd_t;

int main(void) {
    alignas(16) double x[2] = {0,0};
    alignas(16) double y[2] = {0,0};
    alignas(16) double z[2] = {0,0};
    simd_t sx, sy, sz;
    sx = _mm_load_pd(&x[0]);
    sy = _mm_load_pd(&y[0]);
    sz = _mm_mul_pd(sx, sy);
    _mm_store_pd(z, sz);
    std::cerr << "z=" << z[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am building it with g++ (Debian 4.9.3-4) 4.9.3

```
g++ -ftree-vectorize -O2 -msse4 -g -std=c++11 -S test.cpp
```

and looking at the generated assembly:

```
main:
.LFB1789:
    .file 1 "test.cpp"
    .loc 1 6 0
    .cfi_startproc
.LBB37:
    .loc 1 7 0
    pxor    %xmm2, %xmm2
.LBE37:
    .loc 1 6 0
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 48
.LBB44:
    .loc 1 15 0
    movl    $.LC1, %esi
    movl    $_ZSt4cerr, %edi
    .loc 1 7 0
    movsd   %xmm2, (%rsp)
    movsd   %xmm2, 8(%rsp)
    .loc 1 8 0
    movsd   %xmm2, 16(%rsp)
    movsd   %xmm2, 24(%rsp)
.LVL0:
.LBB38:
.LBB39:
    .file 2 "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/emmintrin.h"
    .loc 2 263 0
    movapd  (%rsp), %xmm1
    mulpd   16(%rsp), %xmm1
    movaps  %xmm1, (%rsp)
```

What suprised me is the mulpd instruction at the very end of the assembly listing.  Why is the stack used for one of the operands?  I would expect to see something like

```
    movapd  (%rsp), %xmm1
    movapd  16(%rsp), %xmm2
    mulpd   %xmm2, %xmm1
    movaps  %xmm1, (%rsp)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same (i.e. a load then a multiply), but with one more instruction and clobbering a register in the process, or am I missing something?  Actually maybe my question is why do you expect to see those last four instructions?

Comment: Thanks for the question.  I assumed that both operands of a simd instruction should be xmm registers.  You comment prompted me to do some digging, I see now that the first operand could be a 128 bit memory location.

Comment: Mystery solved ... only one thousand nine hundred and ninety nine more pages of the intel manual to memorise now :)

Comment: What's really weird is that gcc stores zeroes to the stack and then re-loads them.  clang sees through the mul with compile-time-constant data and just prints a 0.0.  The only vector instruction is the `xorps` to zero the register holding the first FP arg.  (godbolt: http://goo.gl/hkVu2t)